# Mod-only page for site-specific close reasons is giving a "Something Bad Happened"

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, 500-server-error

I can't access `/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons` on either of the sites where I'm a moderator ([here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons) and [here](https://literature.stackexchange.com/admin/flags/site-specific-close-reasons)). Clicking the "Manage community-specific close reasons" link from `/admin/links` gives me an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page.

Other moderators report seeing the same, so it's not just me.

What gives?

Comment: Yes, yes it is. :/ Thanks for the report.

Comment: We've identified the problem and a fix should go out tomorrow, thanks for catching this!

Comment: @KylePollard so, how bad was it?

Comment: Not bad at all, that mod page uses a made up placeholder post, and our code was trying to get information from the database about it. "Where is the post with an ID of -1!?"

Comment: @KylePollard Thanks for the quick fix! Btw, the reason I wanted to access that page was to report two typos in it, so expect another bug report on the same topic very soon :-)

Comment: Hmm, this change went out today, but I'm still getting the exception in production. I'll check again tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug, thank you for reporting it.

This page uses a placeholder post to generate the close post notice preview. However, the placeholder had an ID of -1. Some new code incorrectly handled this  id and tried to fetch it from the database, which totally blew up. We've now fixed this bug.

Comment: Thanks! And another thanks to whoever changed "discribe" to "describe" and "this will message will" to "this message will" in that page - no further bug report coming after all :-)